# C++ metafunction to retrieve constexpr from templated base classes

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have code that looks something like this:

```
template <typename Tag, int v>
struct Const
{
    static constexpr int value = v;
};


struct Compound
    :
    Const<struct T1, 111>,
    Const<struct T2, 222>
{
    Compound(); // constructor is not constexpr
};
```

I would like to know a compile-time construct (e.g. metafunction) that given either `struct T1` or `struct T2` as argument can extract as `constexpr int` `111` or `222` respectively from `Compound`.

I think I want a metafunction that looks something like this but don't know how to write it:

```
template <class C, typename Tag>
struct GetConst
{
    static constexpr int value = /* some magic */
};

GetConst<Compound, struct T1>::value == 111
GetConst<Compound, struct T2>::value == 222
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve... Do you want to pass `T1` and `T2` struct to `GetConst` as template param or `Const<Tx, val>` or maybe `Compound` that would inherit from some `Const`?

Comment: Tried to clarify in an edit. Yes, want to pass T1 or T2 as template param and get back the corresponding int (111 or 222) as a constexpr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different syntax ( constexpr function instead of a static member variable), but here you go:

```
template <typename Tag, int v>
constexpr int getVal(Const<Tag, v>) {
    return v;
}

template <class C, typename Tag>
constexpr int GetConst() {
    return getVal<Tag>((C*)nullptr);
}

constexpr int value = GetConst<Compound,T2>();
int main() {        
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because `Compound` isn't allowed to be constructed within a `constexpr` f  - also C might not have copy/move constructors. It might be possible to have `getVal()` take a pointer and it might work???.

Comment: Ah sorry, in my test case, Compound was a POD.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template <typename Tag, int v>
struct Const { static constexpr int value = v; };

struct T1 {};
struct T2 {};

struct Compound: Const<T1, 111>, Const<T2, 222> { };

template <typename Tag, int N>
constexpr auto f(Const<Tag, N>) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, N>{};
};

int main() {
    static_assert((111 == decltype(f<T1>(std::declval<Compound>()))::value), "!");
    static_assert((222 == decltype(f<T2>(std::declval<Compound>()))::value), "!");
}
```

You can add one more function to capture the constant and return it if needed.